# Likelihood function and sampling distribution symbol

Tags: likelihood, notation, sampling-distribution

I read a introductory stat book that the likelihood function has symbol like , e.g., L(theta, x); while the sampling distribution has the symbol like f(x,theta). May I ask does anyone know whether the switch of the theta and x has certain kind of statistical meaning?

Comment: No. $L(\theta, x)$ means a function $L$ has two inputs $\theta$ and $x$. Technically, switching them around does not make any difference in its mathematical/statistical sense; but the order of writing usually is just habit or depends on context. Likelihood function $L$ concerns more with $\theta$ hence it being put first. Sampling distribution may concern more with the random variable $x$ hence it being put first. It does not work always this way, though.

Comment: An alternative convention is to use a conditioning symbol: $f(x|\theta)$ versus $L(\theta|x)$ as this indicates which entry varies, $x$ in the first case versus $\theta$ in the second case (without necessarily assuming $\theta$ is a random variable).

Comment: Thank you very much.